# Symfony2, Is it possible to have two route for one action in a controller?

Tags: symfony, routes

I have an action inside my controller class and I want two different routes like below:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to create a new entity.
 *
 * @Route("/edit/choose/date", name="user_choose_date")
 * @Route("/supervisory/choose/date", name="sup_choose_date")
 * @Template()
 */
public function chooseDateAction()
{
    return array( );
}
```

The reason for that I would like to give the route access to some users but the user role are different.

Let's say:

User with `supervisor` role can access `sup_choose_date`

User with `user` role can access `user_choose_date`

The question is if it is possible to have two different routes for one action? or I have duplicate the code for different routes ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible when using YAML (or XML) routing.

Example:

```
sup_choose_date:
    pattern:   /supervisory/choose/date
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:chooseDate }

user_choose_date:
    pattern:   /edit/choose/date
    defaults:  { _controller: MyBundle:Default:chooseDate }
```

Comment: I could do this with annotation also. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**Worked for me!**

You must set different names; if not, specify explicitly

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I is possible on every kind of format including annotation. It should work as long as you have different name for every route.