# Duplicate ressource with different prefix

Tags: symfony

[SETTINGS]

- Symfony 3
- `DollEntity`, can be a child of itself as .
- `ChocolateEntity`, is a child of DollEntity

[PROBLEM]

My `DollEntity` is like a Russian doll, thus, a doll can contain another doll. 
`ChocolateEntity` will be within the first or second doll.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to have two differents routes to get the chocolate.

**<kbd>src/AppBundle/Resources/config/doll.yml</kbd>**

```
doll_index:
    path:     /dolls/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:index" }
    methods:  GET

doll_show:
    path:     /doll/{idDoll}/show/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:show" }
    methods:  GET

doll_new:
    path:     /doll/new/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:new" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

doll_edit:
    path:     /doll/{idDoll}/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

doll_delete:
    path:     /doll/{idDoll}/delete/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:delete" }
    methods:  DELETE

sub_doll_index:
    path:     /doll/{idDoll}/subDolls/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:index" }
    methods:  GET

sub_doll_show:
    path:     /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/show/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:show" }
    methods:  GET

sub_doll_new:
    path:     /doll/{idDoll}/subDoll/new/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:new" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

sub_doll_edit:
    path:     /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/edit/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:edit" }
    methods:  [GET, POST]

sub_doll_delete:
    path:     /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/delete/
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Doll:delete" }
    methods:  DELETE

#Problem start here
doll_chocolate:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix:   /doll/{idDoll}/

sub_doll_chocolate:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix:   /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/
```

`sub_doll_chocolate` will works while `doll_chocolate` will return me a route not found error.

From testing, I found out that I couldn't do this either

```
doll_chocolate:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix: /doll/{idDoll}/
    prefix: /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/
```

How can I get the two routes working?
Is there a way to have multiple prefix for a single resource?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple routes to one action as long as you define unique identifiers for each route. Do not forget to import the routing that starts from app/routing.yml. Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127414/symfony2-is-it-possible-to-have-two-route-for-one-action-in-a-controller

Comment: @FrankB I indeed found that topic before posting... But mine is a bit different. I'm not using `partern/defaults` but `resource/prefix`. And Symfony doesn't seems to find the first `resource/patern` set when I do it like in the linked topic. I would guess that's because I provide `resource` twice, but I don't know how to work around.

Comment: have you tried to put the definition of `sub_doll_chocolate` before the `doll_chocolate`? And why `.yml.yml` ?

Comment: @Matteo yes I tried, it only reverse the problem, one will give me route not found while the other will work. And .yml.yml was only edit error. Sorry

Comment: @FrankB Just understood why what I'm asking isn't possible... I wouldn't be able to tell which route is what... Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

With Symfony 4.1 you will have the ability to have a route id prefix.
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19612

meaning you can then do something like:

```
sub_doll_chocolate:
    idprefix: sub_doll_
    resource: "@AppBundle/Resources/config/chocolate.yml"
    prefix:   /doll/{parent}/subDoll/{idDoll}/
```

Note: you could already to something similar with FOSRest

Answer (score -1):

I am not quite sure, but I don't think ending your routes with '/' is a good practise. Also the general idea in symfony is that it matches the first route it finds suitable. So you should also check if some other route is not getting matched before it even gets to the doll_chocolate (which is the reason the using the '/' symbol at the end of each right MIGHT turn out to be the problem). I would also suggest that you put less specific URLs in front (so that doll_chocolate goes right after doll_new, and both of these routes are placed right after the doll_index route) You should also check if the url you typed into your browser actually ended with a '/', because it wouldn't match a route

Comment: Thanks for the detailled reply @grssn. No route were matched, only one of the two are working, second get `route not found`. I don't think the `/` is the problem. For fact, when you load the routing of your bundle in `app/config/routing.yml` you set prefix as `/` and your index in your bundle routing file is also `/`. Ending with `/` will simply add it if you didn't when you typed the URL. The route order here changed so it's more easy to point the problem. Netherless, I tried what you said and doesn't solve my problem, I still get `route not found` for one of them.

Comment: I will modify my answer, because now, that I look at it, it might not have been clear that I was actually talking about the path not prefix values, when I mentioned that I did not think it was a good practice to end their values with a '/'. But I tested it and in fact it doesn't look like it would have cause the problems you were experiencing.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in the chocolate.yml file. Could you update your answer to show the contents of that file too and what URL are you using to access that resource when testing?

Comment: That's not an answer to the question.